# How can I Accelerate performance of a double loop in python?

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, optimization

I am wondering is there is a way where I can accelerate a double for loop in python, currently this is my code:

```
for i in range (len(newdata1)):
  for j in range(len(dataset)):
    if str(dataset['date'].values[j]) == str(newdata1['SALEDATE'].values[i]):
        newdata1['QUANTITY'].values[i],newdata1['PRICEWONKG'].values[i] = dataset['apple(kg)'].values[j],dataset['apple($/kg)'].values[j]
```

The code is working correctly but is taking a lot of time since the dataframes size is really big. Is there any way I can reduce the execution time for this double loop?

Thanks

Comment: If these are pandas dataframes, use a join.

Comment: Use pandas vectorized operations.